# Can't find what's wrong with the types here

Tags: haskell

i am working on an encryption algorithm and i have a type problem

i don't understand what's the problem with the types here:

```
multien :: [(Integer , Integer)] -> Integer
multien [] = 1
multien ((x,y):z) = y* multien z

enchelper2 :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> Integer -> Integer
```

the problem is here in enchelper in the `(z:((mod x y),y))` expression:

```
Couldn't match expected type (Integer , Integer) with actual Type [(Integer, Integer)]
```

the z in the enchelper method here i passed it as [] (empty set) the ERROR IS IN COLUMN 40 exactly

```
enchelper :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [(Integer, Integer)] -> [(Integer, Integer)]
enchelper x (y:ys) z = if((enchelper2 (z:((mod x y),y)) (multien z:((mod x y),y))) == x) then z:[] else (z:((mod x y),y):(enchelper x ys z:((mod x y),y)))
```

Comment: and the error is reported where?  (or is that blindingly obvious to a haskell programmer?)

Comment: in the (z:((mod x y),y)) expression

Comment: Could you use Haskell-style comments instead of C++-style comments please. I edited the post and my edit got overwritten.

Comment: No offense, but this code is a mess. I suggest you look into using more higher-order functions. For example, `multien` can be defined much more clearly as `multien = product . map snd`. It's also a good idea to learn some of the basic precedence rules so you don't have to use so many parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your use of the cons operator.  `z` is a list of tuples of two Integers, so if you really want `z` *before* `((mod x y),y)`, what you want to use instead is the `++` operator, followed by a list.

Try this on for size:

```
enchelper :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [(Integer, Integer)] -> [(Integer, Integer)]
enchelper x (y:ys) z = if((enchelper2 (z++[((mod x y),y)]) (multien (z++[((mod x y),y)]))) == x) then z else (z++[((mod x y),y)])++(enchelper x ys (z++[((mod x y),y)]))
```

Or, a bit more readable:

```
enchelper :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [(Integer, Integer)] -> [(Integer, Integer)]
enchelper x (y:ys) z =
    if ((enchelper2 foo (multien foo)) == x)
    then z
    else foo++(enchelper x ys foo)
    where foo = z++[((mod x y),y)]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this piece of code

```
z : (mod x y, y)
```

The types are

```
x :: Integer
y :: Integer
z :: [(Integer, Integer)]
(mod x y, y) :: (Integer, Integer)
```

And note that

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So perhaps you should have instead

```
(mod x y, y) : z
```

There are then similar errors later in the line.